# How can i add two custom text field that has stopwatch time value in hh:mm:ss format (01:15:08) in a formula field so that it can be used in a report

Tags: formula-field

I want to add two custom text field in hh:mm:ss format in a formula field. I have two field in my application that is a stop watch time capture which is stored in text format. In report i need to get the total time for the two time capture, but I don't know how can i manipulate such data to get the result that i wanted in formula field.

Answer (score 0):

You can probably use TIMEVALUE function to convert text to time or you can use substitute and value as mentioned on this thread:
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000E0yhQAC

Here are some other threads i've found:
https://trailblazers.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000pZXhQAM
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=custom_field_time_overview.htm&type=5

You could do the above and convert both fields into one field performing the sum, or convert to two fields and performing an operation in a report.

Comment: when i use time value i need to add '.000' string to my string to get a time value returned, but when i use '+' operator between these two valeus from TimeValue function, it gives me error "Incorrect argument type for operator. +".

I didn't properly understand the second thread, but i am trying that one

Comment: It may be easier if you convert each individual text field into a time field, then do a simple:
Timefield1__C + Timefield2__c in a formula field to get the sum of them, rather than try to perform a sum of both inside one formula field. 

Downsides to this:  2~3 new fields 

Upside to this: Individual reporting going forward allowing you to perform more operations.